# Comma between "because" and a preposition like "in"

Tags: commas

I have seen this both ways, but is it better to do it like the first or second one? Does it change the meaning of the sentence when the comma is added, or is it just a verbal comma?

1.) That's because, in addition to the troubles here, there were other issues.

2.) That's because in addition to the troubles here, there were other issues.

Comment: Research "parenthetical clause".

Comment: Are 1) and 2) exactly what you meant to write?  Is it only about where to place commas?  Punctuation is a matter of convention, to assist a reader.  So, had you written: "That's because in addition.  To the troubles here there were other issues.", you can still still understand what I actually meant.  The full stop does not change the grammar.  Well, I could probably think up a sentence where it appeared to, but strictly, punctuation is merely an aid to following the grammar, not the grammar itself.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about parenthetical clauses. I know that punctuation isn't grammar, which is why I was trying to ask about which version is more commonly accepted I guess?